# get an error from session.save

Tags: hibernate, session, methods

I created a method to save my objects in hibernate. But when saving, I got an error from `session.save(ob);`

> org.hibernate.HibernateException: illegally attempted to associate a proxy with two open Sessions

What is the mistake of my code.

```
public class HibernateSession {

    public static Session getSession() {
        Session session = Connection.NewHibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        return session;
    }

    public static void save(Session session, Object ob) {
        Transaction transaction = session.beginTransaction();
        session.save(ob);
        session.flush();
        transaction.commit();
        session.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error explains it self.

> Illegally attempted to associate a proxy with **two open Sessions**.

Avoid using multiple open sessions. Create a session variable at the top of your class and use it everywhere.

Modify your save method as following to make sure the session is open.

```
public static void save(Session session, Object ob) {
    if(!session.isOpen){
        session = getSession();
    }
    ....
}
```